# How to map an optional one to one relationship in EntityFramework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have 2 models, Registration and RegistrationCode.  A registration may have a single registration code and a registration code may have a single registration.

```
public class Registration
{
    public Registration()
    {
        RegistrationDate = System.DateTime.Now;
    }
    [Key]
    public int RegistrationID { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    public DateTime? RegistrationDate { get; set; }


    public RegistrationCode RegistrationCode { get; set; }
}

public class RegistrationCode
{
    [Key]
    public string Code { get; set; }

    public bool IsUsed { get; set; }

    public Registration Registration { get; set; }
}
```

I've tried mapping the association with Fluent API like so:

```
    modelBuilder.Entity<Registration>()
        .HasOptional(t => t.RegistrationCode)
        .WithOptionalPrincipal();
```

But the problem is when I recreate my database with update-database, my RegistrationCode table has the following fields which suggests something is not right:

```
Code    nvarchar(50)    Unchecked
IsUsed  bit Unchecked
Registration_RegistrationID int Checked
Registration_RegistrationID1    int Checked
```

Can someone suggest how I should do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By your code

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Registration>()
            .HasOptional(t => t.RegistrationCode)
            .WithOptionalPrincipal();
```

you tell EF that there is a principal (`Registration`) of which the association is not part of the model. *Besides* that, there is the `Registration` property in `RegistrationCode`. EF takes this as a second foreign key. The fix is to tell EF that both are the same:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Registration>()
            .HasOptional(t => t.RegistrationCode)
            .WithOptionalPrincipal(r => r.Registration);
```

Answer (score 0):

This would make the one to one or zero relationship between entities.

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<Registration>()
    .HasRequired(m => m.RegistrationCode)
    .WithOptional(t => t.Registration)
```

For more details over relatonship please follow the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/data/jj591620.aspx)

Comment: As I mentioned in the question, both registrations and registration codes are optional, so HasRequired won't work here